# Integral Inequality for symmetric function

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals

Let $f$ be a continuous function from $[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  I want to prove the following result, but I can't even start really.

$$I \equiv \int_0^1 \int_0^1 x \wedge yf(x)f(y)dxdy \ge 0 $$ with equality holding if and only if $f(x) = 0 \quad \forall x \in [0,1]$.  I can obviously make the observation that $I = 2\int_{x \leq y} x f(x) f(y)dxdy$ but this is unhelpful.  Any hints/solutions would be massively appreciated, and I'm sorry to not really have any ideas so far on my own.  Thanks if you can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h_x(t)=0$ for $t >x$ and $1$ for $t \leq x$. Then $\int_0^{1} h_x(t)h_y(t)dt=x\wedge y$. So (by interchanging the order of integration) we can write $$I=\int_0^{1}\int_0^{1}\int_0^{1} h_x(t)h_y(t)dtf(x)f(y)dxdy$$ $$= \int_0^{1}(\int_0^{1}\int_0^{1} h_x(t)h_y(t)f(x)f(y)dxdy) dt$$ $$=\int_0^{1}(\int_0^{1} h_x(t)f(x)dx)^{2}dt \geq 0.$$ Equality holds only when  $\int_0^{1} h_x(t)f(x)dx=0$ for all $t$ which means $\int_t^{1}f(x)dx=0$ for all $t$. This implies $f(x)=0$ for al $x$.